# where is the file syscall_64.tbl in linux 3.13.0-83-gerneric

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

Im trying to add system call in linux in parallels and using linux 3.13.0-83-gerneric version ubuntu.

But I can't find systemcall table in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-83/arch/x86/syscalls route.

This route only have Makefile  syscallhdr.sh  syscalltbl.sh files.

But I dont know what is .sh file and how to edit

where is the system call table in this version's kernel and if syscalltbl.sh is this tablem how to add??
what's different to old version??

Answer (score 1):

The system call table can be found in the CPU architecture specific section of the kernel. For the Intel x86 and x86_64 architectures, it can be found in [arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.13/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl).

If you are interested in considerably more information about how system calls work, I've written a [comprehensive blog post](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/) that explains everything there is to know about system calls from both the kernel and userland. That post also mentions syscall_64.tbl.